# Map `JSON string` to `tree` in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am having `JSON` in the form of `{"Others": null, "Main Hobbies": {"Dance": ["Salsa", "Solo"], "Sports": ["Cricket"]}, "Game": ["PUBG", "Cricket", "Football"]}` '

And i want to convert it into `tree structure` like

```
 data =   [
// not include Others since it is null
{ name: 'Main Hobbies',
  checked: false,
  children: [
      { name: 'Dance', checked: false, children: [ { name: 'Salsa', checked: false },{ name: 'Solo', checked: false }] },
      { name: 'Sports' , checked : false , children [{name :'Cricket',checked:false}]}
  ]
},
{ name: 'Game', checked: false ,children:[{name:"PUBG",checked:false},{name:"Cricket",checked:false},{name:"Football",checked:false}]},
```

Here is how i am using these below functions so far  , but rather than converting it to `tree` structure it is converting into list structure i.e upto only `two levels`.However the desired output is of `Three level`

```js
let data = {"Others": null, "Main Hobbies": {"Dance": ["Salsa", "Solo"], "Sports": ["Cricket"]}, "Game": ["PUBG", "Cricket", "Football"]};
var result = filterData(data);
function filterData(data){
    let result = [];
    for (var key in data){
      var value = data[key];
      let val = data[key];
      if(val){
        if(Array.isArray(val) && val.length>0){
          let ob ={};
          ob['name'] = key;
          ob['checked']=false;
          ob['children'] = getChildren(val);   
          result.push(ob);  
       }else if(typeof val == 'object'){
         let ob ={};
         ob['name'] = key;
         ob['checked']=false;
         ob['chldren']=filterData(val);
         result.push(filterData(val));
       }
    
     }
    }
    return result;
  }
  function getChildren(data){
    let result = [];
    data.forEach(function(e){
      let ob = {};
      ob['name'] = e;
      ob['checked']=false;
       if(Array.isArray(e.children) && e.children.length){
           ob['children'] = getChildren(e.children);
         }
       result.push(ob);  
    })
    return result;
  
    
  }
  console.log(result);
```

```
 ];
```

want to convert `tree nodes` [like here](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/blob/master/example/cli4/src/app/checkboxes/checkboxes.component.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach for objects by checking the type of the handed over data.

```js
function create(data, checked = false) {
    return Array.isArray(data)
        ? data.map(name => ({ name, checked }))
        : Object
            .entries(data)
            .filter(([, v]) => v !== null && (!Array.isArray(v) || v.length))
            .map(([name, value]) => ({
                name,
                checked,
                children: create(value, checked)
            }))
}

var data = { empty: [], Others: null, "Main Hobbies": { Dance: ["Salsa", "Solo"], Sports: ["Cricket"] }, Game: ["PUBG", "Cricket", "Football"] },
    result = create(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: your mind in now hard-wired to do this stuff in half of a second :D

Comment: @Nina Scholz working fine , plz do me a fever like how do handle the case for `[]` similar to `null`

Comment: @NinaScholz what if i want to consider `Null` as well tried `return Array.isArray(data)
        ? data.map(name => ({ name, checked }))
        : Object
            .entries(data).map(([name, value]) => ({
                name,
                checked,
                children: create(value, checked)
            }))` but it is not working

Comment: so for this case `{ name: 'Others', checked: false}`

Comment: then you need this part: `.filter(([, v]) => !Array.isArray(v) || v.length)
            .map(([name, value]) => value === null
                ? { name, checked }
                : { name, checked, children: create(value, checked) }
            )`

Comment: @NinaScholz sir please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62397147/find-and-update-in-nested-json