# Filter Nested array based on some property

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array:

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Main Hobbies",
  "checked": false,
  "children": [{
    "name": "Dance",
    "checked": false,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Salsa",
      "checked": true
    }, {
      "name": "Solo",
      "checked": false
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Sports",
    "checked": false,
    "children": [{
      "name": "Cricket",
      "checked": true
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "name": "Game",
  "checked": false,
  "children": [{
    "name": "PUBG",
    "checked": false
  }, {
    "name": "Cricket",
    "checked": false
  }, {
    "name": "Football",
    "checked": true
  }]
}]

function removeFalseElem(arr) {
  arr.forEach(element => {
    if (Array.isArray(element.children) && element.children.length > 0) {
      element.children = element.children.filter(e => {
        return e.checked === true
      });
      element.children.map(e => {
        delete e['id'], delete e['checked']
      })
    } else {
      removeFalseElem(element.children);
    }
    delete element['id'], delete element['checked'];
  });

}
removeFalseElem(data);
console.log(data);
```

How do I map `name` to `key` and `children` to `array` contains wherever `checked` is `true`. `Main hobies` should contain `Salsa` since it is checked. I just want to inverse the approach of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61395344/map-json-string-to-tree-in-javascript)

output should be like

```
{
  "Main Hobbies": { Dance: ["Salsa"], Sports: ["Cricket"] },
  Game: ["Football"]
}
```

have to keep only `checked:true` values

Answer (score 0):

You could check if a children contains no children and return an array of names or create an object with the checked nodes.

```js
const
    getObject = array => array.every(({ children }) => !children)
        ? array.reduce((r, { name, checked }) => checked ? [...(r || []), name] : r, undefined)
        : array.reduce((r, { name, checked, children = [] }) => {
            children = getObject(children);
            if (checked || children) r[name] = children;
            return r;
        }, {}),            
    data = [{ name: "Main Hobbies", checked: false, children: [{ name: "Dance", checked: false, children: [{ name: "Salsa", checked: true }, { name: "Solo", checked: false }] }, { name: "Sports", checked: false, children: [{ name: "Cricket", checked: true }] }] }, { name: "Game", checked: false, children: [{ name: "PUBG", checked: false }, { name: "Cricket", checked: false }, { name: "Football", checked: true }] }],
    result = getObject(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With following helper methods, traverse the items and build the required output.

1) filter -- given an array return the name which are true

2) hasGrandChild -- whether the given object has children and children object has children.

```js
const process = data => {
  const filter = arr => arr.filter(x => x.checked).map(x => x.name);
  const hasGrandChild = arr => arr.length > 0 && "children" in arr[0];
  const output = {};

  data.forEach(({ name, children }) => {    
    if (hasGrandChild(children)) {
      const obj = {};
      children.forEach(ch => (obj[ch.name] = filter(ch.children)));
      output[name] = obj;
    } else {
      output[name] = filter(children);
    }
  });
  return output;
};

var data = [
  {
    name: "Main Hobbies",
    checked: false,
    children: [
      {
        name: "Dance",
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Salsa",
            checked: true
          },
          {
            name: "Solo",
            checked: false
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "Sports",
        checked: false,
        children: [
          {
            name: "Cricket",
            checked: true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Game",
    checked: false,
    children: [
      {
        name: "PUBG",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: "Cricket",
        checked: false
      },
      {
        name: "Football",
        checked: true
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log(process(data));
```